# CSV Files- Time Tracker

Tags: python

Wanted to get familiarize myself with CSV Files handling and `datetime` library so I wrote this small project where:
    when the user enters a string into the console the program saves the time at which the string was entered and marks it as the start time.
    when the user reenters the same string the activity is considered over and the end time is recorded as well and duration is then calculated.
    At the end of the program everything is saved to three CSV files:

1. `pending.csv`: has one pair of strings, `start_time`, `cs-values`
2. `duration.csv`: has one pair of strings, `time_delta`, `cs-values`.
3. `records.csv`: has three strings, `start_time`, `end_time`, `cs-values`.

The code is looking pretty messy and not straightforward.
Any suggestions?

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
from csv import reader, writer
from parse_time import parse_delta


def display_dict(p: dict):
    '''
    simply displayes the key, value pairs of a dictonary.
    '''
    if len(p) <= 0:
        max_length = 0
        print('Empty...')
    else:
        max_length = max([len(key) for key in p.keys()])
    for key, value in p.items():
        prop_space = ' ' * (max_length - len(key))
        print(key.capitalize(), prop_space, ':', value)
        print('-'*40)      
    print()




time_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f' #python datetime default format.


#read pending activity data from csv file
#reads string, datetime pairs from a csv file and assigns them to a dictionary
#where strings(names of activities) are keys and datetime object(start time of the activity)
#are the values.   

try:
    with open('pending.csv', 'r+', newline='') as p:
        csv_reader = reader(p)
        pending = {}
        for line in csv_reader:
            activity = line[0]
            time = dt.strptime(line[1], time_format) 
            pending[activity] = time
#if the file doesn't exist create it:
except FileNotFoundError:                     
    with open('pending.csv', 'x') as p:
        pending = {}

#read activities durations in days, hours, minutes, seconds data from csv file.
#same procedure but assigns a string, timedelta object pairs.
try:
    with open('duration.csv', 'r+', newline='') as d:
        csv_reader = reader(d)
        durationS = {}
        for line in csv_reader:
            activity = line[0]
            # function to parse the default output string of dt.now() function.
            #and convert it into a timedelta object
            duration = parse_delta(line[1])
            durationS[activity] = duration
except FileNotFoundError:
    with open('duration.csv', 'x') as p:
        durationS = {}


#read records data from csv file.
#gets a dictionary where the keys are activity names(strings) and the values lists
#of lists (d = {key: [ [time, time], [time, time]] , key2:...etc})
try:
    with open('records.csv', 'r+', newline='') as r:
        csv_reader = reader(r)
        records = {line[0]: [] for line in csv_reader}
        r.seek(0)
        for line in csv_reader:
            activity = line[0]
            start_time = dt.strptime(line[1], time_format)
            end_time = dt.strptime(line[2], time_format)
            if activity not in records:
                records[activity] = []
            records[activity].append([start_time, end_time])
except FileNotFoundError:
    with open('records.csv', 'x') as p:
        records = {}

#main command line loop
while True:
    print('_'*40), print()
    display_dict(pending) #display the currently in progress activities
    print()
    print('_'*10, '|')
    new_activity = input('...').lower() #input command.
    print('_'*10, '|')
    print()

    #checking for typos.
    typo = 0
    for char in 'duration':
        if char in new_activity:
            typo += 1
    if typo >= 7 and new_activity != 'duration':
        confirm = input('Did you mean "Duration? "')
        if confirm in ['yes', 'y']:
            new_activity = 'duration'

    #checking required action.
    if new_activity == '':
        break 

    #delete an entry: -pd flag removes entry without user confirmation
    elif new_activity[0:3] == 'del':
        del_activity = new_activity.replace('del', '', 1).lstrip()


        if '-pd' in del_activity:
            pending_duration = 'pd'
        elif '-p' in del_activity:
            pending_duration = 'p'
        elif '-d' in del_activity:
            pending_duration = 'd'
        else:
            pending_duration = ''

        del_activity = del_activity.replace('-pd', '', 1).replace('-d', '', 1).replace('-p', '', 1).rstrip()


        if 'p' in pending_duration:
            if del_activity in pending:
                pending.pop(del_activity)
                print(f'Deleted "{del_activity}" from pending.')
            else:
                print(f'{del_activity} was not found in pending.')
        if 'd' in pending_duration:
            if del_activity in durationS:
                print(f'Deleted "{del_activity} from durations.')
                durationS.pop(del_activity)
            else:
                print(f'{del_activity} was not found in duration')

        #if not 'pd' flag in command: ask user for confirmation before deletion.
        if 'p' not in pending_duration and 'd' not in pending_duration:

            if del_activity in pending:
                confirm = input(f'Delete "{del_activity}" from pending? ')
                if confirm in ['yes', 'y']:    
                    pending.pop(del_activity)
                    print(f'"{del_activity}" succesfully removed from pending activities')

            if del_activity in durationS:
                confirm = input(f'Remove "{del_activity}" from durations log?')
                if confirm in ['yes', 'y']:
                    durationS.pop(del_activity)
                    print(f'"{del_activity}" Succesfully removed form duration.')

        elif del_activity == '':
            print('Usage: del {key}')
        elif 'p' not in pending_duration and 'd' not in pending_duration:
            print("Activity Doesn't Exit")

    #type duration at command line to display current durations list
    elif new_activity == 'duration':
        display_dict(durationS)

    #end activities in progress and save their duration and their start and end times.
    #if a name of a pending activity is entered at command line the activity is assummed 
    #to be finished.
    elif new_activity in pending:
        print(f'"{new_activity}" ended at {dt.now()}')
        duration = dt.now() - pending[new_activity]
        print(f'Duration is: {duration}')
        durationS[new_activity] += duration
        if new_activity not in records:
            records[new_activity] = []
        records[new_activity].append([pending[new_activity], dt.now()])
        pending.pop(new_activity)

    #if entry is a new entry and is not a command ie.: 'del', 'duration', etc...
    else:
        pending[new_activity] = dt.now()
        if new_activity not in durationS:    
            durationS[new_activity] = timedelta(0)
        if new_activity not in records:
            records[new_activity] = []
        print(f'"{new_activity}" Started at {dt.now()}.') #print to the screen the start
                                                          #time of the entered activity
    print(), print(), print(), print(), print(), print(), print(), print() 



#if user exist program before this point the new entry data is not saved and the most recent
#file is perserved 

#overwriting pending data to file.
with open('pending.csv', 'w', newline='') as p:
    csv_writer = writer(p)
    for key, value in pending.items():
        csv_writer.writerow([key, value])

#overwriting duration data to file.
with open('duration.csv', 'w', newline='') as d:
    csv_writer = writer(d)
    for key, value in durationS.items():
        csv_writer.writerow([key, value])

#overwriting records data to file.
with open('records.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as r:
    csv_writer = writer(r)
    for key, value in records.items():
        for time_list in records[key]:
            start_time = time_list[0]
            end_time = time_list[1]
            csv_writer.writerow([key, start_time, end_time])
```

parse_delta file:

```
from datetime import timedelta

def parse_delta(d: str):
    '''
    returns a timedelta object that is parsed from the default
    string format outputed by the datetime.datetime.now() function
    '''
    time = []

    if 'day' in d:
        for char in d:
            if char.isnumeric():
                time.append(char)
            elif char == 'd':
                time.append('')
        days = ''
        time_copy = time.copy()
        for i in range(len(time)):
            if time_copy[i] == '':
                break
            days += time_copy[i]
            time.remove(time_copy[i])
        days = int(days)

        if len(time) == 12: #if hours value is two digits instead of 1
            index = 1
        else:
            index = 2
        hours = int(''.join(time[1: 1 + index]))
        minutes = int(''.join(time[1 + index: 3 + index]))
        seconds = int(''.join(time[3 + index: 5 + index]))

        try: #assigning this varible on timedelta(0) causes an error as there 
        #are no milliseconds in the string
            milliseconds = int(''.join(time[5 + index:])) 
        except:
            milliseconds = 0

    # if string doesn't have any days
    else:

        for char in d:
            if char.isnumeric():
                time.append(char)
        if len(time) == 12:
            index = 1
        else:
            index = 0
        days = 0
        hours = int(''.join(time[0: 1 + index]))
        minutes = int(''.join(time[1 + index: 3 + index]))
        seconds = int(''.join(time[3 + index: 5 + index]))
        try:
            milliseconds = int(''.join(time[5 + index:]))
        except:
            milliseconds = 0
    delta = {'days': days, 'hours': hours, 'minutes': minutes, 'seconds': seconds, 'milliseconds': milliseconds}
    return timedelta(**delta)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### File layout

The choice of splitting your data into three files seems odd to me. I'm not sure what `cs-values` is, but I imagine you can get away with only `records.csv` and columns:

- `start_time`
- `end_time`
- `state`
- `cs_values`

(Underscore for consistency.) Duration wouldn't be useful to store separately since it can be calculated as the difference between the start and end. `state` would be serialized from an enumeration, being `PENDING`, etc.

### Typo

`displayes` -> `displays`

### Negative length?

```
if len(p) <= 0:
```

doesn't make a lot of sense for a `dict`. If you write `if not p`, it will catch both a `None` reference and a zero-length reference. Dictionaries can never have a negative length.

### Inner lists

The brackets should be dropped from this:

```
max([len(key) for key in p.keys()])
```

because you don't need an intermediate, in-memory list.

### display_dict

I'm not sure what this offers that `pprint` doesn't. I would just use `pprint`. The formatting is not exactly the same, but `pprint` has more functionality for nested structures and is a built-in module.

### Global constants

```
time_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f' #python datetime default format.
```

should have a capitalized variable, i.e. `TIME_FORMAT`.

### Unpacking

```
        activity = line[0]
        time = dt.strptime(line[1], time_format)
```

can use unpacking from `line`:

```
activity, time_str = line
```

### Read-or-create

This logic seems odd:

```
try:
    with open('pending.csv', 'r+', newline='') as p:
        csv_reader = reader(p)
        pending = {}
        for line in csv_reader:
            activity = line[0]
            time = dt.strptime(line[1], time_format) 
            pending[activity] = time
#if the file doesn't exist create it:
except FileNotFoundError:                     
    with open('pending.csv', 'x') as p:
        pending = {}
```

If the file does not exist, why create it here? Write mode will create it if it does not exist.

### Did you mean

This:

```
#checking for typos.
typo = 0
for char in 'duration':
    if char in new_activity:
        typo += 1
```

is a somewhat rough string distance. You should read about the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

### Multiple `print`

This:

```
print(), print(), print(), print(), print(), print(), print(), print()
```

can just be replaced by

```
print('\n' * 7)
```

Comment: I meant comma separated values with cs-values. I also wanted a way that enables me to read data from a file without truncating it and in case it doesn't exist; create it. opening a file in 'w+', 'w', 'a+' creates a file if it's not found but truncates the file if it exits.

Comment: opening a file in 'rb+' mode raises a FileNotFoundError if the file does not exits.

Comment: As for separating the data in three files: this is because when reading data from the files at a later time I can differentiate between pending data, duration data and records data. As they all contain similar formats so it will be hard to differentiate them from each other if they are all kept in the same file.

Comment: OK; so for the file mode, https://stackoverflow.com/a/20433067/313768 ?

Comment: This is basically the same as try.. except but using os module

Comment: It's different because (1) it would be done directly before the write, instead of directly after the read; and (2) it doesn't require logic-by-exception, which I consider an anti-pattern.